# How does Vagrant create a private network?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vagrant

What is Vagrant doing behind the scenes to the host and guest machine when it sets up a private network with a fixed IP (http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html)?

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the host side, Vagrant does nothing. As far as I know Vagrant never touches host network configuration.

On the guest side, the current [provider](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/index.html) implements the network configuration logic. Here is what the VirtualBox provider does:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb

Basically the implementation is composed of two sequential steps:

1. Enable all the needed network adapters on the virtual machine, using hypervisor commands;
2. Configure the IP address on the guest OS, using [guest capabilities](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/plugins/guest-capabilities.html), in this case the `configure_networks` capability.

As an example, [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/guests/debian/cap/configure_networks.rb) is the implementation for the `configure_networks` capability on Debian-based Linux OS.

Comment: The "on the host side, Vagrant does nothing" part is certainly wrong. Depending on the configuration, Vagrant creates new networks in VirtualBox...

Comment: In linux, if you run "ifconfig" in your terminal while hosting a virtualbox VM you will see the "vboxnet0" interface created by the provider.

Answer (score 12):

Back in Vagrant 1.0.x it is called [Host-only Networking](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/host_only_networking.html), it is a feature of VirtualBox, which allows multiple virtual machines to communicate with each other through a network via the host machine. The network created by host-only networking is private to the VMs involved and the host machine. The outside world cannot join this network.

Behind the scene, VirtualBox creates a new virtual interface ("loopback") on the host which appears next to the existing network interfaces.

VirtualBox even provide a built-in DHCP server for host-only networking (Private Networking) if no static IPs have been assigned. It can be configured in File - Preferences - Network.

See more at =>

- [Host-only networking](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)
- [Networking in VirtualBox](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1)

Comment: If I'm behind a router. Is the private IP assigned as part of the router? Or is it private to my own machine? How can I make sure that the private network is not assigned to the router, that is it doesn't use the DHCP of the router?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Your router is NOT involved in VirtualBox's private network. You can unplug / disconnect from LAN and you should still be able to use it Private Network (internal network).